# Is it possible to compute the discrete wavelet transform by convolving the input signal with a specific wavelet (at different scales) in MATLAB/python

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, wavelet, wavelet-transform, pywavelets

Below is a diagram of how I plan to do the DWT. How can this be done using Matlab? I do not want to this by sub band coding.

[image: DWT diagram]

Comment: Yes, you can do that by convolution.

Comment: Could you provide me with a code to do so. I don't know how to get the wavelet at different scales in Matlab or Python.

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://github.com/gregfreeman/wavelab850/blob/master/Continuous/CWT_Wavelab.m -- it's a copy of the famous WaveLab toolbox on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how got used to the discrete wavelet transform in MATLAB https://au.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/, the above is the link for the Wavelet toolbox for MATLAB.
Check out the below functions.

dwt-https://au.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/dwt.html?s_tid=doc_ta

wavedec- https://au.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wavedec.html?s_tid=doc_ta

PS if you do not want the decimation of samples at each stage, try out the stationary wavelet transform in MATLAB. ( makes your results redundant according to my understanding.) https://au.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/swt.html